# Mapping or Merging two csv files in python based on two columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two files one contains

```
    0       1

0   0.0     0.0
1   2.0     8.0
2   7.0     3.0
3   6.0     1.0
4   5.0     0.0
5   4.0     NaN
6   9.0     NaN
7   0.0     NaN
```

and another one contains:

```
    0

0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   E
5   F
6   G
7   H
8   I
9   J
```

I want to map the second file with two columns (0 and 1) of the first file.

Expected output is like this:

```
1_st_column   2nd_column 
A             A
C             I
H             D
G             B
F             A
E
J
A
```

I tried with merging but couldn't get it work. How can i solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) here:

```
file1.replace(dict(enumerate(file2['0']))) #replace '0' with original column name
#if column name is int , use: file1.replace(dict(enumerate(file2[0])))
# if needed to create dict with index: file1.replace(dict(zip(file2.index,file2['0'])))
```

---

```
   0    1
0  A    A
1  C    I
2  H    D
3  G    B
4  F    A
5  E  NaN
6  J  NaN
7  A  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying looping and then mapping. But this is much better.

Comment: @Shekhar No problem. happy coding :)